# UPDATE with JOIN and condition SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables and I'm trying to update one of the columns in one of them using the data from the second one. The SQL I have is as follows:

```
UPDATE 
        table_one
SET 
        contents = CONCAT('https://someurl.com/', table_one.id, '.', split_part(T2.file_name, '.', 2))  
FROM 
        table_one T1
JOIN 
        table_two T2
ON 
        T1.id = T2.image_id
WHERE   
        T1.kind IN ('image')
```

What I'm trying to do is take the value of `file_name` column of table `table_two` and insert it into the `contents` column of `table_one` for the given id and for the kind 'image' which is a column of `table_1`. So the update should happen only for the records with kind='image' The split and concat part is done to get the extension of the file.

This works but it updates all of the entries without taking into the consideration the kind which is set to be 'image'. Also it seems it's getting all of the same values because all of the extensions are set the same.

Could anybody point to what I'm doing wrong, please?

**Update:** I'm using Postgres.

Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hi I supect the issue is that you are not using the alias for the update like the following



    UPDATE 
            T1
    SET 
            T1.contents = CONCAT('https://someurl.com/', T1.id, '.', split_part(T2.file_name, '.', 2))  
    FROM 
            table_one T1
    JOIN 
            table_two T2
    ON 
            T1.id = T2.image_id
    WHERE   
            T1.kind IN ('image')

Comment: Please read the [`sql` tag text](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info), then tag your question with the RDMS you're using, provide sample data, current output, and desired output.

Comment: I'm using Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) do not repeat the target table in the FROM clause:

```
UPDATE table_one t1
  SET contents = CONCAT('https://someurl.com/', table_one.id, '.', split_part(T2.file_name, '.', 2))  
FROM table_two T2
WHERE T1.id = T2.image_id
  AND T1.kind IN ('image')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have joined table_one to itself, with no condition to the join.  Therefore you have a cartesian join, and every row gets updated.  `T1.kind IN ('image')` doesn't matter, because you are not updating T1, you are updating table_one.

[Heed the warning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html):

> Note that the target table must not appear in the `from_list`, unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_list).

Just rewrite without the join to T1.  You have to move the join condition from the ON to the WHERE, since there is no way to use ON with an implicit join.

```
UPDATE 
        table_one
SET 
        contents = CONCAT('https://someurl.com/', table_one.id, '.', split_part(T2.file_name, '.', 2))  
FROM 
        table_two T2
WHERE   
        table_one.kind IN ('image') and table_one.id=t2.image_id
```